# On a problem of Berkovich

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, p-groups, outer-automorphisms

What is the real history of the following problem proposed by Berkovich [Y. Berkovich, Z.Janko, Groups of prime power order. Volume 2, Expositions in Mathematics, 56, Walter de Gruyter, New York, 2011]?

1004. (Old problem) Study the $p$-groups $G$ such that $|Aut(G):Inn(G)|_p=p$.

Is there any recorded result on this topic?

Comment: what's $|\cdot|_p$?

Comment: Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then $n_p$ denotes the $p$-part of $n$. That is $n_p=p^k$, where $n=p^km$ and $\gcd(m,p)=1$.

Comment: W. Gasch\"utz has proved that if a $p$-group $G$ is of order $>p$, then $p$ divides $|\text{Aut}(G):\text{Inn}(G)|$. Therefore, the above question is natural.